# CMake can't find include files of libraries

Tags: cmake

I am building a simple template for C/C++ CMake projects. Basically, following cmake.org own tutorial. I deviated a bit from the tutorial, and I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

So, this is the directory structure:

```
template
      +--- CMakeLists.txt
      +--- build/
      |        +--- default/
      +--- include/
      +--- myLibrary/
      |           +--- CMakeLists.txt
      |           +--- include/
      |           |          +--- mylibrary.h
      |           +--- src/
      |                  +--- myfunction.cpp
      +--- src/
             +--- mymain.cpp
```

This is *template/CMakeLists.txt*

```
project(MyProjectName VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(myLibrary)
    
add_executable(myexecutable src/mymain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexecutable PUBLIC MyFunctions)
target_include_directories(myexecutable PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

This is *template/myLibrary/CMakeLists.txt*

```
add_library(MyFunctions src/myfunction.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyFunctions INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

Now, for this to work, my library program (*template/myLibrary/src/myfunction.cpp*) has to include its header file like this:

```
#include "../include/mylibrary.h"
```

Which I find weird, because I am already declaring the include directory of "my Library". I mean this line in *template/myLibrary/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
target_include_directories(MyFunctions INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

I was expecting to be able to include the library header file more directly(?), like this:

```
#include "mylibrary.h"
```

Is that the way it is suppossed to work? or am I missing something?

If I don't include the header like (myfunction.cpp) *#include "../include/mylibrary.h"*.
Or, I don't declare the include directory (myLibrary/CMakeLists.txt) *target_include_directories(MyFunctions INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")*. The compilation fails:

```
../../src/mymain.cpp:9:12: fatal error: 'mylibrary.h' file not found
#  include "mylibrary.h"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTERFACE puts dir only in [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html), while PUBLIC puts dir both in INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and in [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html). So you need use PUBLIC

```
target_include_directories(MyFunctions PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```